# Problem with rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone explain to me why this rewrite rule doens't work:

```
RewriteRule ^architecture/([a-zA-Z_]+)/(.*).html$ web/index.php?field=1&sub=$1&name=$2
```

on this url: http://localhost/greenlinked1-6.com/architecture/projects/84-test-deeplink-test.html

And what I should do to get it working.
I've tried to find the answer in several articles but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` file should be placed in the directory `greenlinked1-6.com`. Make sure there are no conflicting rules, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1 [L]
# This line will never be be matched
RewriteRule ^architecture/([a-zA-Z_]+)/(.*).html$ web/index.php?field=1&sub=$1&name=$2
```

Comment: The .htaccess was in place. Your comment about conflicting rules put me in the right direction though. There is a conflicting rule below this one. I always thought that the first match is applied but apparently that isn't so.

Comment: Is your question answered? If not, provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

check that u havn't used `RewriteBase /` just remove & try again...